# lighttpd + perl + mojolicious =?

Tags: perl, fastcgi, lighttpd, mojo, mojolicious

Does mojolicious working under the lighttpd web-server? How to cofigure? Does I need setup the FastCGI? It's my first usage of lighttpd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use FastCGI but you can also use the included http server in Mojolicious (Hypnotoad) and use Lighttpd as a reverse proxy. So, for example, lighttpd listens on port 80 and proxies requests to one or more Mojoliciouss running at port 8080.

I find this set up easier, but it might be a little slower than using fastcgi... who knows.

edit:

links with more info:

- Docs: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc
- Mentions Appache/FastCGI: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc?Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook
- the two http servers included:

  - http://mojolicio.us/perldoc?Mojo/Server/Daemon
  - http://mojolicio.us/perldoc?Mojo/Server/Hypnotoad